# Elixir app using CQEx fails to start LZ4

Tags: elixir

Apologies for the long-windedness!

I have a small app that uses CQEx to write to Cassandra (for various reasons, I am constrained to Cassandra 2.1, so I have specified `protocol_version: 3` in my `prod.exs` - and in `dev.exs`).

My `mix.exs` contains `{:cqex, "~> 0.2"}` and `{:cqerl, github: "matehat/cqerl"}`.

I'm using Distillery to create a release tarball which is copied to a machine running `Centos 7.2`.

After exploding the tarball I run `bin/app start` and it fails, creating an `erl_crash.dump` file, the first line of which contains `Slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,lz4}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})`.

Oddly, if I run it using `iex -S mix`, it works fine!

I've been staring at it for a while now, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Peter

Comment: Did you add it to your list of applications? `[applications: [:cqex]]`

Comment: What OS do you use _to build a release_? It should be the same as the one running is, i. e. centos 7.2.

Comment: Initially I did not have it in `[extra_applications: ...]` but I added it (just to be sure); it is listed in `app.app`.

Comment: And both the compile and target machines' `/etc/centos-release` report `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mix.exs` include `{:lz4, github: "szktty/erlang-lz4", override: true}` as a dependency

Comment: Thank you, this has worked - I can sell Elixir to my boss now (my inability to get it to talk to Cassandra was a big blocker! :)

I am still a little confused as to why I need to add `:lz4` explicitly to `extra-applications` given that it is specified in `deps` - my understanding (which may be wrong) is that it should be automatically included in started applications by virtue of it being in `deps`.

Comment: You are correct, you should not need to include :lz4 in extra applications. I updated my answer to reflect the change.